# Type Error thrown during Multiprocessing while trying to append results to a shared list

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize a function that appends results to a shared list using the multiprocessing library and keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'ListProxy' and 'Int'`

I think the part that is tripping me up is the appending to append each result to a shared list. If I take this part of the code out, the script runs fine. However, the whole point in running this script is to append a lot of things to one list.

A google search tells me that this error is caused because i am "comparing a sequence to an integer". I get what the error is saying, but I don't know how to interpret it in terms of the multiprocessing library

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Below is a simplified version of the code I am trying to use

```
import lasio
import glob 
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Manager


#generates a list of filepaths to be fed to the parralelization
wellfiles = []
for file in glob.glob(....filedierctory...//*):
    wellfiles.append(file)


def process_file(filepath,L):
    #read the file
    las = lasio.read(filepath)
    #extract the value I want from the file
    uwi = las.well[11].value
    #print the value
    print(uwi)
    #append the value to a shared list. THIS IS WHERE I THINK THINGS ARE FAILING
    L.append(uwi)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        L = manager.list()
        p = Pool(5)
        p.map(process_file, wellfiles,L)
        p.join()
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything